# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre "como" y "ya que"?

Tags: gramática, conjunciones

Pensaba que eran los mismos pero parece que no es así, ya que encontré una alternativa en una comprensión de lectura para DELE C1, que tiene ambas palabras como opciones:

> Pero este proceso solo puede remontarse hasta determinada época, _ _ _ _ después las palabras empezaron a cambiar tanto que es imposible definir qué está relacionado con qué.
>
> a) así que b) ya que c) como

La clave dice "ya que"

Consulté el diccionario y me parece que "como" solamente se usa en el principio de una frase, mientras que "ya que" se usa en el principio de una frase *o* después de la coma. ¿Estoy en lo correcto?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sí, es como dices, aunque no es habitual encontrar "Ya que" al principio de una frase, las dos  partículas se usan para especificar implicación, y la diferencia principal es donde se usan en la frase. Un ejemplo:

Supongamos que A implica B. Podríamos decir:

> Como A, B.

o:

> B, ya que A.

y, aunque es mucho menos habitual (y suena más forzado, menos natural y no lo recomiendo):

> Ya que A, B.

Comment: `Ya que` me parece como la `Now that..` en inglés.  Y `como` me parece como la "Since...".  `Since A, B...` `Now that A, B`